# 2015 Macbook Pro running Catalina keeps restarting while in use

Tags: macbook-pro, restart, reboot

I've had this issue intermittently over the last ~month or two where I'll be doing something on Chrome on my laptop and it will suddenly restart; usually the screen freezes, the audio repeats its last beat a handful of times, and then it goes through the rebooting process.

The only known issue is that I have way too many Chrome tabs, but I also use a plugin to keep them from using too much memory (The Great Suspender).

Does anyone know what is causing this and what I can do to stop it from happening going forward? The main concern is that it might reboot while I'm in the middle of an important video call (which thankfully hasn't happened yet).

If it would be of assistance and if it doesn't contain any identifying information, I could post the problem report (the message is all greek to me and very long so I don't know if it's okay to post or not).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with getting things to a “base state”. Chrome is a memory hog, but adding a 3rd party utility to limit memory use is not fool proof.  There’s no guarantee that the plugin itself isn’t without fault and is causing the issues that you installed it in the first place to try and mitigate.

Comment: If you don't get the problem with another browser -- MS Edge, or Safari -- then it's a Chrome problem. Try contacting the developers .

Answer (score 0):

You start by not opening so much tabs, or you can try a different plugin like RabbitMQ because the plug-in Could be the case.